# Design issue Android platform

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to build a view when i click it will add views under it 
like the view [image]

when i clicked on this button i want to add views under it like this 
[image]

So How i can make it in XML and Java ?

Comment: It sounds as though you will want to extend the spinner class with a custom layout of your own choosing.

Comment: @jay snayder good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create all the views in an .xml file or in several after you include them in the main view.xml

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/vista1"
    layout="@layout/vista1"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/vista2"
    layout="@layout/vista2"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

or

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vista1" android:visibility="gone"> ... </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vista2" android:visibility="gone"> ... </LinearLayout>
```

according to your view if it is linearlayout, relativelayout 
in your java class

```
LinearLayout vista1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vista1);
LinearLayout vista2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vista2);
....
vista1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
vista2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I hope to help